# How the jwt tokens are actually being created within jwt.io website?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have an application that is working with JWT token-based authorization.

I crated a JWT token with the jjwt dependency. Just out of curiosity I used the same secret key, same payload,same header and same hashing algorithms and tried to create a jwt token from the jwt.io website. Unfortunately the signature of the token generated there is entirely different than the one that I manually created in the code.

Can someone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: is the signature just different or also invalid when you verify it with your program? For identical input (identical header, payload, key) you ge get identical output (signature). Identical means identical strings. If there's only one bit difference, the signature will be totally different. Whitespace doesn't count, as it's stripped before the base64 conversion. It mighht be helpful to see your code to generate the token and the two different tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the JWT is the output from a hashing function.  The output of this function may depend on fields *other* than the ones you mentioned.  For example, your JWT may have an Issued At Time (`iat`) field, which would not be the same for the two tokens you are examining.  If so, then the checksums from the two tokens also would not be the same.

My general suggestion here would be to verify that *all* fields from your JWT really are the same.

Comment: Yes, I know that. When my server creates tokens I will get a different token for the same user in each API call. Because I am setting an expiration for the tokens. and that expiration time is like current time + 2 days. But that is not the case here. I am getting the token and I paste it in the jwt.io website, and grab the header and payload, and trying to create a new jwt token with the exact same values with the same secret key that is being used by my server. This time the token is not generated by my server.

Comment: @jithinMV Are you sure that the `jwt.io` site and your code are using the same algorithm to generate the signature?

Comment: Yes they both use HS512